# Spark Java: How to sort ArrayType(MapType) by key and access the values of the sorted array

Tags: java, apache-spark, collections, mapping, sql-order-by

So, I have a dataframe with this schema:

```
StructType(StructField(experimentid,StringType,true), StructField(descinten,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,true),true),true))
```

and the content is like this:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|experimentid    |descinten                                                    |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1             |[[x1->120.51513], [x2->57.59762], [x3->83028.867]]           |
|id2             |[[x2->478.5698], [x3->79.6873], [x1->341.89]]                |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to sort "descinten" by key in ascending order and then take the sorted values. I tried with mapping and sorting each row separately but I was getting errors like:

> ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to scala.collection.Map

or similar. Is there a more straight forward way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested I managed to solve it with map and TreeMap for sorting. My aim was to create vectors of the values in an ascending order based on their key.

```
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                        new StructField("expids",DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
                        new StructField("intensity",new VectorUDT(),false,Metadata.empty())
            });
            Dataset<Row> newdf=olddf.map((Row originalrow) -> {
                    String firstpos = new String();
                    firstpos=originalrow.get(0).toString();
                    List<scala.collection.Map<String,Double>>mplist=originalrow.getList(1);
                    int s = mplist.size();
                    Map<String,Double>treemp=new TreeMap<>();
                    for(int k=0;k<s;k++){
                        Object[] exid = JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(mplist.get(k)).values().toArray();
                        Object[] kvlist= JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(mplist.get(k)).keySet().toArray();
                        treemp.put(exid[0].toString(),Double.parseDouble(kvlist[0].toString()));
                    }
                    Object[] yo1 = treemp.values().toArray();
                    double[] tmplist= new double[s];
                    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
                        tmplist[i]=Double.parseDouble(yo1[i].toString());
                    }
                    Row newrow = RowFactory.create(firstpos,Vectors.dense(tmplist));
                    return newrow;

            }, RowEncoder.apply(schema));
```